# How to measure the query run time

Tags: toad

how to find the exact sql query run time in toad.

Answer (score 0):

Force TOAD to retrieve all rows. How? For example,

```
select count(*) from (your current query goes here);

or

select distinct (your current column list goes here) from ...

or

create table test as (your current query goes here)
```